# How else can I express the concept of 'to not play it safe'

Tags: expression-choice

I'm using this expression in an essay at the moment, but I feel that it is coming across syntactically awkward. To put it into context: "...a reflection of my need to not play it too safe elsewhere." Are there other ways to convey the same concept so it flows better?

Edit: I've already used the work 'risk' twice in the same paragraph.

Comment: "...a reflection of my need **not to play it safe in other parts of my life.**"

Comment: "adventurous" is a good euphemism for being more open to trying things that might open new paths vs choosing routes with known outcomes. "less conservative in my choices" might be another way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"to take chances".

"... a reflection of my need to take chances elsewhere."

Answer (score -1):

How about something like:

"...a reflection of my devil-may-care instincts elsewhere..."